# Remove coil connector on 2004 Infinity G35 engine

Tags: ignition-coil, connector, infiniti, g35

My son is replacing the timing chain on an 2004 Infinity G35.  He needs to remove the wiring harness with the coil connectors.  The last connector is a bit different, and we can't figure out how to get it off.  We've tried pushing in on the tab, but that doesn't seem to work.  Also, we notice, that the tab on this one, is green, instead of gray like the other ones. Is there a trick to this, or is the connector broken?

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I *believe* the green part is a positive lock which must be moved out of the way to get to the clip part which holds it in place. If this is the case, it looks like the green part would slide up towards the wires.